# Why was my duplicate flag declined when the question is now marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41355/complementary-color-scheme-doesnt-work), a migrated question, as a duplicate of [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41351/color-scheme-not-working) by the same guy because they're exact duplicates. It is now closed as a duplicate just as I flagged.

However, my duplicate flag was declined. Can someone explain why this happened?

Comment: I won't do it just yet to avoid any more confusion, but for these migration situations you can alternatively flag for mod attention and suggest a merge of the two questions so we can have all the existing answers in the same place

Answer (score 1):

It might have been removed when I was trying to migrate the answer to that question to the other one because a member was rep'd it could have declined it. Once the answer is migrated from that question the question will be deleted because I think the OP isn't aware that duplicate questions aren't allowed on multiple stack sites.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* it takes a mod to close duplicates if they are migrated questions. - A mod migrated it, so only a mod can say it's a duplicate - Just guessing though. If you'd have flagged the non-migrated question, the close vote would have been accepted.